# Can't Add JTextField to Frame Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I've this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Pattern extends JComponent
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panelBody;
    private JPanel panelMenu;
    private JPanel panelAll;
    private GridLayout glBody;
    private GridLayout glMenu;
    private BorderLayout bl;
    private ArrayList<JLabel> label;
    private ArrayList<JTextField> tf;
    private ArrayList<JButton> button;
    private ArrayList<JButton> buttonMenu;

    public Pattern()
    {
        label = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        tf = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
        button = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        buttonMenu = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    }

    public void createFrame(String title)
    {
        this.frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(1500,1500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
    }

    public JFrame getFrame()
    {
        return this.frame;
    }

    public void setBorderLayout()
    {
        this.bl = new BorderLayout();
    }

    public BorderLayout getBorderLayout()
    {
        return this.bl;
    }

    public void setGridLayoutBody(int a, int b)
    {
        glBody = new GridLayout(a,b);
    }

    public void setGridLayoutMenu(int a, int b)
    {
        glMenu = new GridLayout(a,b);
    }

    public GridLayout getGridLayoutBody()
    {
        return this.glBody;
    }

    public GridLayout getGridLayoutMenu()
    {
        return this.glMenu;
    }

    public void createPanel()
    {
        this.panelAll = new JPanel();
        this.panelAll.setLayout(this.getBorderLayout());
        //this.panelAll.add(this.panelBody);
    }

    public void createPanelBody()
    {
        this.panelBody = new JPanel();
        //this.panelMenu.setLayout(this.getBorderLayout());
        this.panelBody.setLayout(this.getGridLayoutBody());
    }

    public void createPanelMenu()
    {
        this.panelMenu = new JPanel();
        //this.panelMenu.setLayout(this.getBorderLayout());
        this.panelMenu.setLayout(this.getGridLayoutMenu());
    }

    public JPanel getPanelBody()
    {
        return this.panelBody;
    }

    public JPanel getPanelMenu()
    {
        return this.panelMenu;
    }

    public JPanel getPanel()
    {
        return this.panelAll;
    }

    public void addLabel(JLabel l)
    {
        this.label.add(l);
        this.panelBody.add(l);
    }

    public ArrayList<JLabel> getLabel()
    {
        return this.label;
    }

    public void addTextField()
    {
        this.panelBody.add(new JTextField());
    }

    public ArrayList<JTextField> getTF()
    {
        return this.tf;
    }

    public void addButton(JButton b)
    {
        this.button.add(b);
        this.panelBody.add(b);
    }

    public void addButtonMenu(JButton b)
    {
        this.buttonMenu.add(b);
        this.panelMenu.add(b);
    }

    public ArrayList<JButton> getButton()
    {
        return this.button;
    }

    public void createMenu()
    {
        this.createPanelMenu();
        this.setGridLayoutMenu(16,1);
        this.panelMenu.setLayout(this.getGridLayoutMenu());
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("K-Nearest Table Classifier"));
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("Heaviside"));
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("Forward Pass"));
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("Backward Pass"));
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("Naive"));
    }

    public void addToPanel()
    {
        this.panelAll.add("West", this.panelMenu);
        this.panelAll.add("North", this.panelBody);
    }

}

class MainPattern
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern knear = new Pattern();

        knear.createFrame("K-Nearest Clasifier");

        knear.setBorderLayout();

        knear.setGridLayoutBody(2,2);

        knear.createPanel();

        knear.createPanelBody();

        knear.createMenu();

        knear.addLabel(new JLabel("K = "));

        knear.addTextField();

        knear.addButton(new JButton("Calculate!"));

        knear.addButton(new JButton("Reset!"));

        knear.addToPanel();

        knear.getFrame().setContentPane(knear.getPanel());
    }
}
```

I don't know why, every time i am trying to add text field to the frame, the output will be empty frame. However, if don't add text field to the frame (just add label or button), it's work perfectly. What is wrong with my code? Then, i want to know what is the difference between JTextField and TextField in Java? Thank you very much.

Comment: why to add field manually? do you have something to do to with the layout to get it displayed?

Comment: I just want to learn about how create java gui manually. However, any suggestion for ide to create gui in java? FYI, i am using mac os lion. Thanks

Comment: java is platform independent, by means that you install your os compatible jre and drawing virtually translating points into bytecode

Comment: The difference between `JTextField` and `TextField` is the first is lightweight and the other is heavyweight.  Lightweight components share a native peer (typically the top level window) and are responsible for painting themselves.  Generally, you shouldn't mix light and heavy weight components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you've set the frame visible BEFORE you've added anything to it.

You should always, where possible, setup you UI before showing the frame.

In you case, simply calling `knear.getFrame().invalidate();` after `knear.getFrame().setContentPane(knear.getPanel());` while fix the problem

**Updated**

You could also include a `repaint` just to be sure ;)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Pattern extends JComponent
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panelBody;
    private JPanel panelMenu;
    private JPanel panelAll;
    private GridLayout glBody;
    private GridLayout glMenu;
    private BorderLayout bl;
    private ArrayList<JLabel> label;
    private ArrayList<JTextField> tf;
    private ArrayList<JButton> button;
    private ArrayList<JButton> buttonMenu;

    public Pattern()
    {
        label = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        tf = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
        button = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        buttonMenu = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    }

    public void createFrame(String title)
    {
        this.frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(1500,1500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
    }

    public JFrame getFrame()
    {
        return this.frame;
    }

    public void setBorderLayout()
    {
        this.bl = new BorderLayout();
    }

    public BorderLayout getBorderLayout()
    {
        return this.bl;
    }

    public void setGridLayoutBody(int a, int b)
    {
        glBody = new GridLayout(a,b);
    }

    public void setGridLayoutMenu(int a, int b)
    {
        glMenu = new GridLayout(a,b);
    }

    public GridLayout getGridLayoutBody()
    {
        return this.glBody;
    }

    public GridLayout getGridLayoutMenu()
    {
        return this.glMenu;
    }

    public void createPanel()
    {
        this.panelAll = new JPanel();
        this.panelAll.setLayout(this.getBorderLayout());
        //this.panelAll.add(this.panelBody);
    }

    public void createPanelBody()
    {
        this.panelBody = new JPanel();
        //this.panelMenu.setLayout(this.getBorderLayout());
        this.panelBody.setLayout(this.getGridLayoutBody());
    }

    public void createPanelMenu()
    {
        this.panelMenu = new JPanel();
        //this.panelMenu.setLayout(this.getBorderLayout());
        this.panelMenu.setLayout(this.getGridLayoutMenu());
    }

    public JPanel getPanelBody()
    {
        return this.panelBody;
    }

    public JPanel getPanelMenu()
    {
        return this.panelMenu;
    }

    public JPanel getPanel()
    {
        return this.panelAll;
    }

    public void addLabel(JLabel l)
    {
        this.label.add(l);
        this.panelBody.add(l);
    }

    public ArrayList<JLabel> getLabel()
    {
        return this.label;
    }

    public void addTextField()
    {
        this.panelBody.add(new JTextField());
    }

    public ArrayList<JTextField> getTF()
    {
        return this.tf;
    }

    public void addButton(JButton b)
    {
        this.button.add(b);
        this.panelBody.add(b);
    }

    public void addButtonMenu(JButton b)
    {
        this.buttonMenu.add(b);
        this.panelMenu.add(b);
    }

    public ArrayList<JButton> getButton()
    {
        return this.button;
    }

    public void createMenu()
    {
        this.createPanelMenu();
        this.setGridLayoutMenu(16,1);
        this.panelMenu.setLayout(this.getGridLayoutMenu());
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("K-Nearest Table Classifier"));
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("Heaviside"));
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("Forward Pass"));
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("Backward Pass"));
        this.addButtonMenu(new JButton("Naive"));
    }

    public void addToPanel()
    {
        this.panelAll.add("West", this.panelMenu);
        this.panelAll.add("North", this.panelBody);
    }

}

class MainPattern
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern knear = new Pattern();

        knear.createFrame("K-Nearest Clasifier");

        knear.setBorderLayout();

        knear.setGridLayoutBody(2,2);

        knear.createPanel();

        knear.createPanelBody();

        knear.createMenu();

        knear.addLabel(new JLabel("K = "));

        knear.addTextField();

        knear.addButton(new JButton("Calculate!"));

        knear.addButton(new JButton("Reset!"));

        knear.addToPanel();

        knear.getFrame().setContentPane(knear.getPanel());
        knear.getFrame().invalidate();
        knear.getFrame().repaint();
    }
}
```